# Access Inkscape Item In SVG From JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, inkscape

I am using a map of the US by counties in SVG format. I did not generate this map. It has PATH elements like:

```
  <path
     style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel"
     d="M 445.51998,291.515 L 451.69098,290.644 L 452.25298,290.563 L 452.85298,294.444 L 453.25798,297.212 L 447.56998,298.055 L 448.71498,296.347 L 448.73698,296.297 L 448.98998,295.683 L 449.04798,295.354 L 448.86298,294.795 L 448.70098,294.58 L 446.99298,293.975 L 446.58298,293.98 L 446.24498,294.044 L 445.92498,294.134 L 445.51998,291.515"
     id="12057"
     inkscape:label="Hillsborough, FL" />
```

What I want to do is on mouse hover for a popup text to appear with the county name.
In this example we see the name is held in `inkscape:label="Hillsborough, FL"`. I am having a problem in getting this value. I have tried various versions of:

```
this.label
this.inkscape.labe
...
```

Each of these fail with undefined or null errors.
How can I read this content in javascript?
Current system specs are jQuery 1.7.2 and d3js v2 running on a ASP.NET site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work to read the attribute value (using the ID of the element in your sample):

```
var myLabel = $('#12057').attr('inkscape:label');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. The inkscape attributes are stored as a NamedNodeMap:

```
itemClick = function( evt ) {
        var obj = evt.target;
        var label = obj.attributes['inkscape:label'].nodeValue;
        window.alert('Object: ' + obj.id + ' Clicked, Label: ' + label);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select this element with jQuery, but you can't manipulate it, that's not what jQuery was made for, but you can use [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) to select and manipulate that path.

Actually i think there is an example just like that in the Raphael Demos Page.

Comment: I do not want to manipulate the object. I just want to read it into a var and display it.

Comment: It would still be easier to do it with Raphael, trust me check it out

Comment: Adding a new js library is pretty much a no go unless this is the absolute only possible way to get this element read - which seems highly unlikely.